# How to escape "${}" in cloudformations "Fn::Sub"

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I want this resource to work with the `!Sub` (or `Fn::Sub`) intrinsic function

```
Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/${aws:username}'
```

The `aws:username` is a [policy variable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) that mustn't be replaced.

One solution would be to use `Fn::Join` instead and write a bit more boilerplate code.

Better: Can you escape the `${aws:username}` so that `!Sub` will work here? <strike>Unfortunately, the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) does not mention anything about escaping.</strike>

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You actually can escape `$` characters with `${!}`.

So your resource would look like this:

```
Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/${!aws:username}'
```

It is mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) under the string parameter section.

> To write a dollar sign and curly braces (${}) literally, add an
> exclamation point (!) after the open curly brace, such as ${!Literal}.
> AWS CloudFormation resolves this text as ${Literal}.

Comment: Yep, it was in the documentation. I'm feeling so silly right now.

Comment: That's a weird way to escape tho

Comment: @mana Don't feel silly. There are a billion AWS doc pages - easy to miss things.