# How do I escape the $ symbol in cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I was looking through similar questions, but this does not quite answer my question

[How to escape "${}" in cloudformations "Fn::Sub"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458304/how-to-escape-in-cloudformations-fnsub?rq=1)

I have a subsection of

```
AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
    commands:
        somecommandwithargs -a $aws/something/somethingelse
```

Here the cloudformation init is evaluating $aws to a blank string since its interpreting it as a variable.

I want to keep it EXACTLY as $aws/something/somethingelse

I cannot find the documentation in CFN docs that states how to escape $ symbols in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's not evaluated by CloudFormation, as it only processes the `!Sub` function. Dollar sign is nothing special in YAML, as it has no processing logic, it's just a data structure.

It's probably being properly saved as a launch configuraiton but then, at runtime evaluates to blank string.

Comment: "at runtime evaluates to blank string" - that statement is true. But the fact that it even does that outside the context of Fn::Sub is something i do not quite understand.

Comment: But can you check the actual commands? I'm 99% sure, that CloudFormation does not evaluate that and passes the string literaly. I think that the command is fine, and just at the time of command execution (that's what I meant by run-tine, not CFN run-time), the shell variable is not there.

Comment: Again, its not a shell variable. I literally want to put $aws in as is.

Comment: Which is still not a CloudFormation issue - this is literally executed shell command. It's not evaluated by CloudFormation. Maybe try using single quotes (') they are not evaluated by Bash.