# Issues for escaping brackets, backslash and double quotes on YAML Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm struggling with putting a `sed` command into a YAML AWS CloudFormation template, which is handled from a [serverless](https://serverless.com/) template.

So, the command I need to execute inside my `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` block is:

```
sed -i.bak '/PRE_CLASSPATH=/c\PRE_CLASSPATH="${MW_HOME}/bi/bifoundation/jdbc/jdk18/bijdbc.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${WL_HOME}/modules/net.shibboleth.utilities.java-support.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${WL_HOME}/modules/org.slf4j.slf4j-api.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${PRE_CLASSPATH}"' /opt/oracle/config/domains/bi/bin/setDomainEnv.sh
```

First I had issues with `${Variables}` since Serverless thought they were variables it should concern about. I workarounded it using a `!Join` function to break up the command in this way ([this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44460789/7820212) doesn't work on Serverless):

```
cmd03_01:
  command: !Join 
    - ''
    - - sed -i.bak '/PRE_CLASSPATH=
      - '/c\PRE_CLASSPATH="'
      - '$'
      - '{MW_HOME}/bi/bifoundation/jdbc/jdk18/bijdbc.jar'
      - '$'
      - '{CLASSPATHSEP}'
      - '$'
      - '{WL_HOME}/modules/net.shibboleth.utilities.java-support.jar'
      - '$'
      - '{CLASSPATHSEP}'
      - '$'
      - '{WL_HOME}/modules/org.slf4j.slf4j-api.jar'
      - '$'
      - '{CLASSPATHSEP}'
      - '$'
      - '{PRE_CLASSPATH}"'
      - ' /opt/oracle/config/domains/bi/bin/setDomainEnv.sh'
```

This doesn't produce the desired output since someone (Serverless or CloudFormation or YAML interpreter) is scaping the backslash and the double-quotes.

My result is something like:

```
sed -i.bak '/PRE_CLASSPATH=/c\\PRE_CLASSPATH=\"${MW_HOME}/bi/bifoundation/jdbc/jdk18/bijdbc.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${WL_HOME}/modules/net.shibboleth.utilities.java-support.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${WL_HOME}/modules/org.slf4j.slf4j-api.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${PRE_CLASSPATH}\" /opt/oracle/config/domains/bi/bin/setDomainEnv.sh
```

As you can see, is adding an extra '' on the current '' character and on the double-quotes.

I tried to escape the string on my YAML to avoid this behavior, but it was worst.

Any ideas or suggestions to have my literal command on the YAML template?

Thanks

Comment: Escaping in yaml is explained [here](https://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2534365)

Comment: I think I tried everything explained there. With single quotes style and with double-quotes also. Maybe it is not a YAML issue, but a Serverless or CloudFormation issue.

Comment: Its not CloudFormation nor YAML. Where did you get "My result " printout from?

Comment: I got it by printing out the metadata.json generated by CloudFormation on the EC2 instance at /var/lib/cfn-init/data/metadata.json.

Comment: Maybe its serverless. I'm not sure how serverless framework is parsing the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I was a little dizzy about seeing so many special characters and I lost my way.

At `/var/lib/cfn-init/data/metadata.json` I was seeing something like this:

```
"cmd03_01":{
  "command":"sed -i.bak '/PRE_CLASSPATH=/c\\PRE_CLASSPATH=\"${MW_HOME}/bi/bifoundation/jdbc/jdk18/bijdbc.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${WL_HOME}/modules/net.shibboleth.utilities.java-support.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${WL_HOME}/modules/org.slf4j.slf4j-api.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${PRE_CLASSPATH}\"' /opt/oracle/config/domains/bi/bin/setDomainEnv.sh"
},
```

So, I thought that was wrong since I was seeing the **"** and **\** characters scaped. That was my confusion. That is OK since that key in that JSON file is a string, so the content of the string has to be properly scaped.

Here I left two ways of declaring a sed command like my example in a serverless template:

**#1**

```
cmd01:
  command: sed -i.bak '/PRE_CLASSPATH=/c\PRE_CLASSPATH="${MW_HOME}/bi/bifoundation/jdbc/jdk18/bijdbc.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${WL_HOME}/modules/net.shibboleth.utilities.java-support.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${WL_HOME}/modules/org.slf4j.slf4j-api.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${PRE_CLASSPATH}"' /opt/oracle/config/domains/bi/bin/setDomainEnv.sh
```

**#2**

```
cmd03_02:
  command: !Join 
    - ""
    - - sed -i.bak '/PRE_CLASSPATH=/c
      - "\\"
      - PRE_CLASSPATH=
      - "\""
      - $
      - "{MW_HOME}/bi/bifoundation/jdbc/jdk18/bijdbc.jar"
      - $
      - "{CLASSPATHSEP}"
      - $
      - "{WL_HOME}/modules/net.shibboleth.utilities.java-support.jar"
      - $
      - "{CLASSPATHSEP}"
      - $
      - "{WL_HOME}/modules/org.slf4j.slf4j-api.jar"
      - $
      - "{CLASSPATHSEP}"
      - $
      - "{PRE_CLASSPATH}"
      - "\"'"
      - ' /opt/oracle/config/domains/bi/bin/setDomainEnv.sh'
```

I hope this saves time for someone.