# Bash script inside Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to deploy a `Sagemaker` Lifecycle with `AWS CloudFormation`.
The Lifecycle is importing `ipynb notebooks` from `s3` bucket to the `Sagemaker notebook` instance.
the bucket name is specified in the parameters, I want to use it in a `!Sub` function inside the `bash` script of the Lifecycle.
The problem is that the `CF` runs first on the template and tries to complete its own functions (like `!Sub`) and then the scripts upload as bash script to the Lifecycle.

This is my code:

```
LifecycleConfig:
  Type: AWS::SageMaker::NotebookInstanceLifecycleConfig
  Properties: 
   NotebookInstanceLifecycleConfigName: !Sub
   - ${NotebookInstanceName}LifecycleConfig
   - NotebookInstanceName: !Ref NotebookInstanceName
   OnStart: 
    - Content:
      Fn::Base64: !Sub 
       - |
        #!/bin/bash -xe
        set -e
        CP_SAMPLES=true
        EXTRACT_CSV=false
        s3region=s3.amazonaws.com
        SRC_NOTEBOOK_DIR=${Consumer2BucketName}/sagemaker-notebooks
        Sagedir=/home/ec2-user/SageMaker
        industry=industry
        notebooks=("notebook1.ipynb" "notebook2.ipynb" "notebook3.ipynb")
        download_files(){
          for notebook in "${notebooks[@]}"
            do
             printf "aws s3 cp s3://${SRC_NOTEBOOK_DIR}/${notebook} ${Sagedir}/${industry}\n"
             aws s3 cp s3://"${SRC_NOTEBOOK_DIR}"/"${notebook}" ${Sagedir}/${industry}
            done
        }
        if [ ${CP_SAMPLES} = true ]; then
          sudo -u ec2-user mkdir -p ${Sagedir}/${industry}
          mkdir -p ${Sagedir}/${industry}
          download_files
          chmod -R 755 ${Sagedir}/${industry}
          chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user ${Sagedir}/${industry}/.
        fi
       - Consumer2BucketName: !Ref Consumer2BucketName
```

Raised the following error:

```
Template error: variable names in Fn::Sub syntax must contain only alphanumeric characters, underscores, periods, and colons
```

It seems that was a conflict with the Bash Vars and the !Sub CF function.

In the following template I changed the Bash Vars and removed the {}:

```
LifecycleConfig:
  Type: AWS::SageMaker::NotebookInstanceLifecycleConfig
  Properties: 
   NotebookInstanceLifecycleConfigName: !Sub
   - ${NotebookInstanceName}LifecycleConfig
   - NotebookInstanceName: !Ref NotebookInstanceName
   OnStart: 
    - Content:
      Fn::Base64: 
       !Sub 
        - |
         #!/bin/bash -xe
         set -e
         CP_SAMPLES=true
         EXTRACT_CSV=false
         s3region=s3.amazonaws.com
         SRC_NOTEBOOK_DIR=${Consumer2BucketName}/sagemaker-notebooks
         Sagedir=/home/ec2-user/SageMaker
         industry=industry
         notebooks=("notebook1.ipynb" "notebook2.ipynb" "notebook3.ipynb")
         download_files(){
           for notebook in $notebooks
             do
              printf "aws s3 cp s3://$SRC_NOTEBOOK_DIR/${!notebook} $Sagedir/$industry\n"
              aws s3 cp s3://"$SRC_NOTEBOOK_DIR"/"${!notebook}" $Sagedir/$industry
             done
         }
         if [ $CP_SAMPLES = true ]; then
           sudo -u ec2-user mkdir -p $Sagedir/$industry
           mkdir -p $Sagedir/$industry
           download_files
           chmod -R 755 $Sagedir/$industry
           chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user $Sagedir/$industry/.
         fi
        - Consumer2BucketName: !Ref Consumer2BucketName
```

The problem here is the `for` loop is not running through all the notebooks in the list but importing only the first one.
After going through some solutions I tried adding `[@]` to the notebooks:
`for notebook in $notebooks[@]`
and
`for notebook in “$notebooks[@]“/”$notebooks[*]“/$notebooks[@]`
I got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that was a conflict with the Bash Vars and the !Sub CF function.

That's correct. Both bash and !Sub use `${}` for variable substitution. You can [escape the bash variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44458304/492773) with `${!}`. For example:

```
for notebook in "${!notebooks[@]}"
```

Also mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html):

> To write a dollar sign and curly braces (`${}`) literally, add an exclamation point (`!`) after the open curly brace, such as `${!Literal}`. AWS CloudFormation resolves this text as `${Literal}`.